# Render both text and FontAwesome icon in function return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to format a date using moment as follows:
`let formattedStartDate = moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');` `

And later trying to return that formatted date, along with a FontAwesomeIcon object from the same function. So far my attempts look something like this:

```
return `${formattedStartDate} <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRight}/>`;
```

However this displays the date correctly, but [Object object] in place of the icon. I understand that this is because the FontAwesome object is indeed an object, but I'm unsure as to how to go about returning the actual icon from the same function. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: Rest of function:

```
formatDateRange(startDate, endDate) {
        let formattedStartDate = moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        let formattedEndDate = moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

        return (
            <>
            {formattedStartDate + ' '}
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRight}/>
            {formattedEndDate}
            </>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Seems like an inappropriate mixing of concerns in your function.

Comment: @isherwood So it's impossible to return both the string for the date and the fontawesome object? It does feel like something that should be achievable, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Didn't say that, but a function should really do one thing.

Comment: Might help if you provided more context. It's hard to make suggestions based on two lines of code.

Comment: @isherwood sure, I'll edit the rest of the function in, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Backticks allow interpolation for a **JavaScript** string - but you want to render React elements, so use JSX syntax instead.

```
return (<>
  {formattedStartDate + ' '}
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRight}/>
</>)
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this, but there didn't seem to be any change at all in my results, it still just returned [Object object].

Comment: That shouldn't happen given the code. Double check that you saved the new version and aren't accidentally still running the old cached version.

Comment: I've edited in the rest of the function, but it does appear to still be rendering Object object even after a hard refresh.

Comment: I can't reproduce. By any chance are you using the results of the call of `formatDateRange` improperly? Eg you'll want `{formatDateRange(someDate1, someDate2)}` in your JSX